# Intepreting definition of integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis

So in my book they prove that if a function f is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ then f is integrable on that interval. I'm not sure how to interpret the following:

*Let $\epsilon$ be a given positive number. Because f is continuous on a closed limited interval there is a number $\delta$ > 0 such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$ for every $x,y \in [a,b] $ such that $|x-y|<\delta$.*

How is $\epsilon$ chosen?

Is it given beforehand so it's a fixed number?  Why do they divide $\epsilon$ with b-a? Is it because $b-a$ is the maximum possible interval length in $[a,b]$ and so $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$ is the smallest possible ratio possible when we divide $\epsilon$ with an interval length?

Answer (score 0):

You set the value of $\epsilon$ (which can be absolutely arbitrary)  just to meet the second part of the proof, which is:

If you take a partition $\mathcal P$ of $[a,b]$ such that the intervals length are $< \delta$ (same of you first sentence).

Then on each interval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ of $\mathcal P$ there exist $x_i$ and $y_i$ such that $m_i = f(x_i)$ and $M_i = f(y_i)$, (using the [Extreme Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) and the fact that $f$ is continuous in a compact, $[a,b]$).

Now the oscillation is given by $$\omega_i = M_i - m_i = f(y_i) - f(x_i) < \color{#f05}{\frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)}}$$

again because of you first sentence, notice that $b -a$ is the length of your inteval. The last part is

$$\require{cancel}\sum \omega_i (t_{i} - t_{i-1}) <  \frac{\epsilon}{\color{#f05}{(b-a)}}\underbrace{\sum  (t_{i} - t_{i-1})}_{= (b-a)} =  \frac{\epsilon}{\color{#f05}{\cancel{(b-a)}}} \color{#05f}{\cancel{(b-a)}} = \epsilon$$

This shows that $f$ is integrable.